# Texture shape extrude in three.js

Tags: canvas, 3d, three.js, webgl, uv-mapping

I'm trying to texture an extruded shape in Three.js. In the following code I create a curved shape, extrude the shape, then create a mesh with the geometry and a material I've loaded from a Jpg file. The wireframe displays but the texture does not. The texture is 512*512px in size.

Am I using the correct approach? Do I need to manually UV map the texture? I'd like the texture to wrap to the entire extruded face instead of each individual quad.

```
var x = -50, y = 20, z = 150;
var rx = 0, ry = Math.PI/4, rz = 0;
var scale = 1;
var color = 0x00ff00;

var shape = new THREE.Shape();

shape.moveTo( x, y );
shape.quadraticCurveTo(x+50, y, x+100, y+50);
shape.quadraticCurveTo(x+50, y, x, y);      

var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/checkerboard.jpg');        
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map:texture, doubleSided:true });

/* 3D */
var extrudeSettings = { amount: 100 };
extrudeSettings.bevelEnabled = false;
extrudeSettings.steps = 1;

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );       

//var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, [ material, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, wireframe: true, transparent: true } ) ] );
mesh.position.set( x, y, z);
mesh.rotation.set( rx, ry, rz );

scene.add( mesh );
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExtrudeGeometry` was originally written to extrude fonts, and the UVs it creates for you likely will not work. You have to manually provide UVs.

Check the source, and you will see you can optionally replace `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.WorldUVGenerator` with your own.

Comment: I ended up just using Blender to calculate the UVs for me. Thanks for your help!